# Why don't I get a solution when adding x >= A constraint in pyscipotp?

Tags: python, optimization, pyscipopt

Adding a simple example (working on much harder but the problem is the same) - it's price/profit optimal combination.

When I add this constraint everything breaks (simple constraint to x > A)

```
for j in range(N):
      model.addCons(x[j] >= A[j])
```

> Warning: SCIPgetSolVal cannot only be called in stage SOLVING without a valid solution (current stage: 10)

While without it everything works ok

Comment: Maybe the model became infeasible. You may want to share the solver log.

Comment: Thanks, it became inseasible with my formulation of problem  and another fromulation is required.